# a teenager eager to return to college

Tags: grammar

everyone,

> *I became a medical curiosity, attracting some of the area’s top
> specialists to look in on me and review my case. As a patient, and **a
> teenager eager to return to college**, I asked each doctor who examined
> me, “What caused my disease?*”

*source; ‘*The Starch Solution: Eat the Foods You Love, Regain Your Health, and Lose the Weight for Good*’ by John McDougall, Mary McDougall

While I understand the bold part above as ‘a teenager [(who was) eager to return to college]’, can I reduce it as ‘a teenager [to be eager to return to college]’? Considering the examples below, I assume such a reduction (from a relative clause to a to infinitive phrase) might be possible but I need your clarification with grammatical reference.

(1) Find a friend [who can help you study].
= Find a friend [to help you study].

(2) There were a lot of people here [who saw the movie].
= There were a lot of people here [to see the movie].

Would appreciate your responses.

Comment: "who saw the movie" <> "to see the movie".   The finite clause declares that the seeing took place, whereas the non-finite clause expresses purpose or intent in your example.

Comment: @TimR Then, do you think the pattern of the example (1) with 'to infinitive phrase' could be applied to the one of my original sentence?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to do with **eager to return to college**.  The word **eager** there is an adjective with a non-finite clause complement expressing the specific nature of the eagerness.  "... a teenager **to be** eager to ..." is ungrammatical

Comment: @TimR I would appreciate it if you kindly explain me why "... a teenager to be eager to ..." is ungrammatical, later on when convenient.

Comment: This is an ungrammatical sentence: "As a teenager **to be** eager to return to college, I took the first train in the morning."  This is a grammatical sentence: "It is hardly unusual for a teenager to be eager to return to college."  Were you thinking of something like the second sentence?

Comment: @TimR Thanks for your responses so far.

Answer (score 0):

You are recommended to find a friend *for the purpose of* helping you to study.

The people were there *for the purpose of* seeing the movie.

*Eager to return to college* is simply a phrase describing the teenager. It is in no way similar to your two examples. *A teenager to be eager* is not an idiomatic English expression.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.